# Rewriting dependent functions

Tags: coq, dependent-type

I am trying to define the predecessor function for binary natural numbers (lists of bits). I want to restrict the input of my function to numbers that are trimmed (do not have leading zeros) and that are positive (So, I do not have to worry about the predecessor of zero).

Here is the definition of the operator `pred`:

```
Program Fixpoint pred (nat1: Nat) (H1: is_trim nat1 = True) (H2: is_pos nat1 H1 = True): Nat :=
  match nat1 with
  | Empt => _
  | Fill Zer nat2 => Fill One (pred nat2 H1 H2)
  | Fill One nat2 => Fill Zer nat2
  end.
```

My first obligation is as follow:

```
nat1: Nat
H1: is_trim nat1 = True
H2: is_pos nat1 H1 = True
H3: Empt = nat1
______________________________________(1/1)
Nat
```

But, I do not know how to solve it.

The contradiction is obviously in `H2`. But, because it depends on `H1`, I cannot just `rewrite nat1` with `Empt` and then `(is_pos Empt H1)` with `False`.

How should I prove this ?

Comment: Also, `dependent-types` should be a tag.

Comment: `dependent-type` (singular) is a tag.

Comment: I just noticed that this goal is `trivial`. (-_-') Still, I would like to know how to solve it by hand in case I stumble into something similar but more complex.

Comment: Wonder why it didn't solve it automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This goal is indeed trivial in that you can return any natural number for the Empt case, and rest assured that nobody can reach that number because they first have to pass in a proper `H2 : is_pos nat1 H1`.

I believe the next "correct" way to solve such a thing is to use a dependent pattern-matching, in the lines of:

```
Program Fixpoint pred (nat1: Nat) (H1: is_trim nat1 = True) (H2: is_pos nat1 H1 = True): Nat :=
  match nat1 as nat1' return is_pos nat1' H1 -> Nat with
  | Empt => fun isposEmpt =>
      (* hopefully, is_pos Empt H1 immediately reduces to False, and you can do this: *)
      False_rec Nat isposEmpt
  | Fill Zer nat2 => fun _ => Fill One (pred nat2 H1 H2)
  | Fill One nat2 => fun _ => Fill Zer nat2
  end H2.
```

That is, you require a proof that nat1 is positive as an argument of your match, and you conclude in the Empt case that the proof is bogus, so you can return bogus too.

Hopefully this works and makes some sense. Please provide the necessary definitions next time to help people play with your example.